# filtering HTML table with JavaScript - no plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

UPDATE:

I am still unable to render any data. My basic strategy, which has worked with sorting is to write a function to filter named filterCats and then call it as a callback in getFilterBreed. This approach seems to do nothing. This approach is below:

```
               function getFilterBreed(){       
                    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                        var cats = cats;
                        filterCats(cats, criteria);
                    });
                }

                function filterCats(cats, criteria){
                    //renderData(cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;}));
                    var criteria = document.getElementById('filter').value;
                    var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;});
                    renderData(filteredData);
                }
```

And the HTML:

```
                    <label for="filter">Filter</label>
                    <input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onchange="filterBreed()" />
```

I have also tried this approach which makes the data in my table disappear:

```
function filterCats(){
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(result) {
                    var cats = result;  // redundant, but kept for readability
                    var criteria = document.getElementById('filter').value;
                    var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;});
                    renderData(filteredData);
                });
            }
       <label for="filter">Filter</label>
       <input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onchange="filterCats()" />
```

My JSON file named cat.json looks like this but is much bigger:

```
[{
                    "breed" : "Abyssinian",
                    "country" : "Ethiopia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "espresso",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Gustav_chocolate.jpg/100px-Gustav_chocolate.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Aegean",
                    "country" : "Greece",
                    "coffeePreference" : "medium roast, cream and sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Aegean_cat.jpg/100px-Aegean_cat.jpg"
}]
```

Lastly I am rendering the data accordingly, which works:

```
               function renderData(cats){
                        var output='<table id="indextable" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
                        output+="<thead>"
                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<th> HeadShot </th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedBreedData()'>Breed</button></th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCountryData()'>Country</button></th>";
                        output+="<th><button onclick='getSortedCoffeeData()'>CoffeePreference</button></th>";
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</thead>"

                    for (var i in cats) {
                        output+="<tbody>" 

                        output+="<tr>";
                        output+="<td><img src='" + cats[i].picture+"' alt='missing cat picture'></td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].breed + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].country + "</td>"
                        output+="<td>" + cats[i].coffeePreference + "</td>"
                        output+="</tr>";
                        output+="</tbody>" 

                    }
                    output+="</table>";
                    document.getElementById("catTable").innerHTML=output;
                }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"No libraries"` - uses jQuery

Comment: what is the actual question?

Comment: To clarify Shomz... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson

Comment: @Shomz  I apologize for the semantics. I should have said no plugins. The question is, it seems like my function filterData should be pulling from my input field and working. Why is this not happening? I am not asking you to do any work for me. I am just trying to learn basic front end JS. Thanks!

Comment: @simon I am trying to figure out how to pull data from my HTML form id = filter into my function filterData.

Comment: Oh I see now. You should probably update the question text and the title (note that you also said "pure Javascript" which just furtherly emphasizes the "no libraries" part), so people know what you need. In the meanwhile, I'll take a look at your code.

Comment: @Shomz cool. I updated to clarify my question, and I will now update title. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've corrected a few mistakes you made, explained them, and hopefully provided a working code.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so this is your input that calls the filter function (note: no function arguments):

```
<input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onchange="filterCats()" /></br></br>
```

Next, this is your filter function, yet it takes one argument:

```
function filterCats(cats){
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        var cats = cats;
        var criteria = document.getElementById("filter").value;
        var filteredData = cats.filter(function(cats){return cats.breed === "criteria";});
        renderData(cats);
    });
}
```

Then, in your getJSON callback, you have a parameter with the same name as the outer function argument; the same thing happens one more time in the inner filter function.

Another thing: `return c.breed === "criteria";` This is comparing the breed value to the string literal "criteria", not the criteria value you got from the filter input, so unless your cat breed is "criteria" this will never evaluate to true - it should be: `return c.breed === criteria;` instead.

---

Finally, after getting rid of many cats and fixing the criteria, we have something like:

```
function filterCats(){
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(result) {
        var cats = result;  // redundant, but kept for readability
        var criteria = $('#filter').val();
        var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;});
        renderData(filteredData);
    });
}
```

This code is not tested, but it should work.

---

You can furtherly optimize this code by passing the criteria value directly to the function:

```
<input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onchange="filterCats(this.value)" />

function filterCats(criteria){
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        renderData(cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;}));
    });
}
```

---

Simple live example:

```js
var improvizedCatsObject = [
  {name: 'shomz',  breed: 'answerer'}, 
  {name: 'robinette',breed: 'questioner'}, 
  {name: 'not pure js',breed: 'jquery'},
  {name: 'is a library',breed: 'jquery'}
];

function filterCats(criteria) {  
  renderData(improvizedCatsObject.filter(function(c) {
    return c.breed == criteria;
  }));
}

function renderData(res) {
  var out = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    out += '<p>' + res[i].name + '</p>';
  }
  $('#res').html(out);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="filter" value="" id="filter" onkeyup="filterCats(this.value)" />
<span>Try inputting "answerer" or "questioner" (no quotes)</span>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: function filterCats(){
    $.getJSON('cats.json', function(result) {
        var cats = result;  // redundant, but kept for readability
        var criteria = $('#filter').val();
        var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed === criteria;});
        alert(filteredData[0]);
    });
} returns undefined. filteredData appears to be capturing any data. filteredData[0].breed doesn't work either.

Comment: You must input an existing breed so you could get some results - see the live demo I wrote. I also could be your returning JSON, I have no idea what it looks like.